# Applying LinearGradientBrush to Path

Tags: wpf, xaml

`Path` with `LinearGradientBrush`:

```
<Path Data="M76,261 C273,301 166.53234,85.564862 274.5,301.5"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Height="148.664"
      Margin="76,203.836,0,0"
      Stretch="Fill"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Width="323.5"
      StrokeThickness="10">
  <Path.Stroke>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.05,0.0"
                         StartPoint="0.0,0.0"
                         SpreadMethod="reflect">                    
      <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>                    
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Path.Stroke>            
</Path>
```

[image]

How to apply `GradientBrush` to `Path` so that transition lines (gradient stops) are perpendicular to tangent to `Path` at every point of `Path`?

Something like this (i'm not a pro in Photoshop):[image]

Comment: Look at this blog: Graphical Paths with Gradient Colors  http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/02/Graphical-Paths-with-Gradient-Colors.html.   This does what you want and has the source code so that you can implement it.

Comment: @KyleHancock Thank you! It looks great!